# Submitting bank information in plain text - isn't this illegal?

Tags: web-services, security, credit-card

I just logged into my online credit card account and was getting ready to make a payment, however I needed to add a new payment method. In doing so, just out of curiosity I opened the Chrome Developer Tools and looked at the network tab to view the request data I was sending, and it seems that everything I put in (credit card number, bank account number, bank routing number, etc.) is all sent directly to their servers in plain text.

Is this legal? I thought it was against the law to send/store this kind of information in your servers, let alone send it via the internet in plain text since that can be intercepted?

I'd like someone with more knowledge on the subject to explain this to me please, as I may be misinformed.

**Edit**: I guess a better question may be, are members of the FDIC allowed to store such information on their own servers? Because according to their legal information, they are a member of the FDIC.

Comment: It's definitely against PCI guidelines...if they are in the US.

Comment: According to their contact page, they are based in NY and Utah.

Comment: The FDIC plays no role in this. Membership is irrelevant.

Comment: Is there any way to report their site then?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Answer (score 1):

The communication between your Chrome web browser and the bank site expected to be thru HTTPS, i.e. secure connection. Check this always when you need to enter clear payment details anywhere in web.

Chrome Tool as the network tool just show the HTML Forms and Items values which were sent thru HTTP/HTTPS protocol.

For sure at some stages of payment request you need to enter payment, card or bank account details. The payment services which processed such details should be PCI complain and depending of situation can store these details. Usually encrypted on their side.